# Is there any way to generate composite image from different smaller images in php?

Tags: php, imagick

I need to generate image on fly when user configure the item of store. It is like building item of his/her shape and configuration. For e.g. When user select sofa set, he will have ability to choose color, design of its corner etc.

Reference site:[Refer this link](http://www.micasa.ch/de/products/getConfigurator)

Comment: Yes code it and they will come. However, **you have to code it, this is not a free coding site**

Comment: @RiggsFolly: i am ready for that, but i was looking for some image cropping library which assist me and give well structured image.

Comment: Your be better of using [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageMagick http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

The Imagick::coalesceImages, Imagick::combineImages and Imagick::montageImage functions seem to be what you are looking for.

There are also functions for changing hue, saturation, brightness and many more.